# Check multiple cells and display the one that is true

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have four cells, L26, L27, L28, and my result in L29.  Depending on data in the sheet L26 will display `0` or `500`, L27 `0` or `1000`, and L28 `0` or `2000`.  In cell L29 I need it to display the highest result.

So for example:

if L26 says `500` but L27 and L28 both have `0`s  I want L29 to display `500`.
if L26 is `500`, and L27 is `1000`, I need L29 to display `1000`.
if L26 is `500` and L27 is `1000`, and L28 is `2000`, I need L29 to display `2000`.

It seems a simple nested If statement should work but I always receive an error.

Comment: anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With nested IFs:

```
=IF(L28=2000;2000;IF(L27=1000;1000;IF(L26=500;500;0)))
```

but I prefer:

```
=MAX(L26:L28)
```